# Object property read access change to write access across units

Tags: delphi

Something I am stuck with. I am sure it is a simple solution.

I have a `frmUnit1` and `dmUnit1`. `dmUnit1` is declared under `Uses` in `frmUnit1`.

`dmUnit1` has `ADOConnection1`, `ADOQuery1`, and `DataSource1`.

Everything works, however if I add `ADOQuery1.Active := True;` in `frmUnit1`, I get errors at compile-time:

> E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ADOQuery

> E2029 Cannot assign to a read-only property

I added `var ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;` which solved the E2003 and E2029 errors.

But when I run the app, I get an error at runtime on `ADOQuery1.Active := True;`:

> Access violation at address 0C00200. Read of address 0C00200

Comment: Your unit ``dmUnit1`` normally contains a globally declared variable for the datamodule instance. Write this variable in unit ``frmUnit1`` before whatever you wanna access from the datamodule, e.g. ``MyDataModule.ADOQuery1.Active := True;``

Comment: By adding the `ADOQuery1` variable in `frmUnit1`, you cleared the compiler errors, but you didn't set that variable to point at anything at runtime, which is why you got the AV.